# selected 3D model on camera view in vuforia SDK

Tags: ios7, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on augmented reality project using vuforia unity extension for iOS. I have a list of 3d models(.3ds). i want 3D models should placed on camera view when user selected a model from that list. I did put 3D models in to my project asset.Is there any tutorial available to render 3D models on camera view? Please help me.

Comment: check this link - https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-drag-teapot

Answer (score 1):

I'm alos looking for same and i got one another SDK you can try for this SDK :"metaio SDK.framework"

This is the link
https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/ios/creating-a-new-ar-application/

you can check this link:

http://augmentedev.com/augmented-reality-sales-design/

Comment: note: augment (free app on android and ios) is not based on metaio